# UE4 Is anyone know why the 4.26.2 ARKit for some devices keeps black?

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit, unreal-engine4

Is anyone know why UE4.26.2 ARkit for some devices will always keeps black?

I use the Default AR project to test it, for **some device** with project build from **UE4.26.2**, the Camera will **keeps black**, but it **can actually detect& tracking the plane,** just can't display.

Same project build from **UE4.25** for same devices, **all works good**, is anyone know why this happened?

I'm going to check the source code about the Apple ARKit.

Any hint will be appreciated, thanks in advances!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out with the UE4.26.2 source engine, there are two steps:

1. Copy the ARkitCameraMaterial from UE4.25 to AppleARKit content folder
2. Inside "AppleARKitVideoOVerlay.cpp", change the OverlayMaterialPath to the path that "ARKitCameraMaterial" located, then it works on my case

By the way, don't change & re-apply this material, cause there is a function depreciated by UE4.26, but this way takes some time cause need build the source engine, hope it can help you guys!